# Android ArCore Animated 3D Objects Not Animation movements not working

Tags: android, arcore

I'am working on a app in that i need to use 3d Animated Model's and I downloaded 3D Animated Model and Imported using AR SceneForm Successfully but i'am not getting Animation Effect of 3D models how to Acieve this, can Anyone suggest me please ?

Comment: Hi, can you please provide URL which model you have downloaded? So I will check in my code using your model than direct you why animation does not work or how to work.

Comment: @DarshanMistry link is https://www.mixamo.com/#/?page=1&type=Motion%2CMotionPack